# Google Earth kml screen overlay with a link

Tags: hyperlink, kml, google-earth

Folks,

I'd like to create a kml which would always display an icon in the top left corner of the GE view. In addition, clicking the icon should open a placemark balloon/webpage/smthg with some additional information.

I can think of two potential solutions: 1) a screen overlay with an embedded link and  2) a placemark with absolute screenXY coordinates. Unfortunately, I can not find a single example of either of these and that makes me wonder if this is doable at all?

Any help highly appreciated,

anssi

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Sure, but with no success. I've looked for screenXY for placemarks, but they seem not to exists. I've looked for internal variables (e.g. ViewTlX or similar) which would allow me to put a placemark in the corner of current view, but can't find anything. Embedding the link in a CDATA section seem not to work either.